# show blank in combobox bind to data base

Tags: combobox

i am binding my combobox to the database and i am able to populate the combobox from my database.But when i am opening the page the combobox contains one value by default from the database. I want to show blank in my combobox, How can do that?

```
my code:
```

datatable dt;

```
DataAccess.Connect();
            dt = DataAccess.Select("select * from CompanyMainActivity");
            cmbMainActivity.DisplayMember = ("name");
            cmbMainActivity.ValueMember = "MainActivityCode";
            cmbMainActivity.DataSource = dt;
```

I try this code, but in dosent work

cmbMainActivity.Items.Insert(0, "select name from CompanyMainActivity");

Answer (score 1):

You can add a blank value at the first.

```
dt = DataAccess.Select("select name, MainActivityCode from CompanyMainActivity");

//Insert default row
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["name"] = String.Empty;
dr["MainActivityCode"] = -1; //I have set -1 because it should not be duplicate and this record is fake. so, we can determine that the record is fake from the -1 value.
dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0); //Insert the blank record at the top of the all records.

cmbMainActivity.DisplayMember = ("name");
cmbMainActivity.ValueMember = "MainActivityCode";
cmbMainActivity.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess what u r looking for are called place holders.Please refer these few links which might help.

```
[Combo box's different properties][1](http://www.dotnetperls.com/combobox)
[If u r using wpf controls][2](http://pwlodek.blogspot.in/2009/11/watermark-effect-for-wpfs-textbox.html)
[check this also][3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/bg182878.aspx)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using WPF

On the combobox's section on your xaml file add a SelectedIndex

```
<ComboBox>
   ...
   SelectedIndex = -1
   ...
</ComboBox>
```